# SQL query execution fails

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to execute query and it doesnt work.

```
SELECT id, 
       idOperacije, 
       idRadniNalog, 
       sum(kolicina) as total
FROM `artikli_presetorijum_zapisi` 
WHERE idRadniNalog = 9 
AND idOperacije = 105 
AND total > 2000
GROUP BY idOperacije
```

Error I get is:

> Unknown column 'total' in 'where clause' Even if I use sum(kolicina)
> in where statement I get same issue.

I need to sum(kolicina) for idRadniNalog and idOperacije and display only items where sum is higer than 2000

Answer (score 1):

You can't refer to an alias or an aggregate in the `WHERE` clause.  Move the restriction on the total to the `HAVING` clause.

```sql
SELECT idOperacije, SUM(kolicina) AS total
FROM artikli_presetorijum_zapisi
WHERE idRadniNalog = 9 AND idOperacije = 105
GROUP BY idOperacije  
HAVING total > 2000;
```

Note that as we are aggregating by `idOperacije` only this column and aggregates of other columns belong in the `SELECT` clause.

Answer (score 0):

The where clause filters the rows used to execute the query. You're trying to get only the rows that have sum > 2000 so you need to use the HAVING clause after the GROUP BY one.
In this way you filter the first rows you impact in your query, you group them in groups of 'idOperacije' and verify the condition you need on those groups (the sum is not a column of your db i think so you can't use it as a condition for where).

Answer (score 0):

Items in the `WHERE` clause are evaluated as each row is encountered, *before* the grouping is finished, and therefore you can't use items that need aggregate functions (like `SUM()`). Instead, put that condition in the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT id, idOperacije, idRadniNalog, sum(kolicina) as total
FROM `artikli_presetorijum_zapisi` 
WHERE idRadniNalog = 9 and idOperacije = 105 
GROUP BY idOperacije 
HAVING sum(kolicina) > 2000
```

It's also poor practice to include items in the `SELECT` clause that are not also either accounted for in the `GROUP BY` clause or aggregated with a function like `SUM()`. Specifically, the `id`, and `idRadniNalog` fields are non-deterministic here, and it might be possible to get different results each time you run the query. Most databases don't even allow this (MySql is kind of bad this way). You should include these in your `GROUP BY` clause *even if the existing `idOperacije` field is enough to uniquely identify those values*.

```
SELECT id, idOperacije, idRadniNalog, sum(kolicina) as total
FROM `artikli_presetorijum_zapisi` 
WHERE idRadniNalog = 9 and idOperacije = 105 
GROUP BY idOperacije, id, idRadniNalog
HAVING sum(kolicina) > 2000
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT idOperacije, idRadniNalog, sum(kolicina) as total
    FROM `artikli_presetorijum_zapisi` 
     group by idOperacije ,idRadniNalog
    HAVING SUM(kolicina)>2000
```

You can use a HAVING clause to test the value of an aggregate function.
It doesn't even have to be the same aggregate used in the projection. You
can evaluate different functions over different columns (and combine them with logical expressions) as long as it makes sense to apply the aggregate over the specified group.  The same grouping will be used for all the aggregate expressions.

Answer (score 0):

I am also getting the same problem when I use the alias name with any Column...
Just try this code this time it will work.

```
SELECT id, 
       idOperacije, 
       idRadniNalog, 
       sum(kolicina)
FROM `artikli_presetorijum_zapisi` 
WHERE idRadniNalog = 9 
and idOperacije = 105 
and sum(kolicina) > 2000
group by idOperacije
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).